# Rest API Returning Formula String Instead of Value

Tags: rest-api, api

On a custom Opportunity object, there is a custom close date field that has a formula calculated default value. However when I attempt to query this field via the REST API, I get the formula itself as a string instead of the value (values have been replaced for privacy) even on records that have been updated with an actual close date rather than using the default value. The API authorized user has the correct permissions to read both the custom Opportunity object as well as Profiles. There are no field-level permissions applied either. Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Request:

`GET /services/data/v59.0/query?q=SELECT%20FIELDS(ALL)%20FROM%20C_S_Opportunity__c%20LIMIT%201`

Respose:

```
"Close_Date__c" => "(IF($Profile.Name=\"Test\", now()+100 ,(IF(OR($Profile.Name=\"Test2\", CONTAINS($Profile.Name,'ASDF')), now()+90 ,IF(OR($Profile.Name==\"Test3\",CONTAINS($Profile.Name,'Test4'),CONTAINS($Profile.Name,'WXYZ')) ,null,now()+100)))))"
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: The REST API endpoint + params is what is needed here.

Comment: @cropredy Apologies - endpoint and params have now been added to the question!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If you do SOQL on the same record (say from the IDE or Developer Console), do you get the same result?

Comment: What happens if you select only the field itself, instead of `FIELDS(ALL)`?